# does new instance of actor get created when too many msg?

Tags: akka, actor

I recently learned about the akka,but some idea I can't grasp.
  my question is, if there are too many message in queue,will a new actor be created?

in many framework,for example, one http-requet message coming,and the framework found that the current "worker" are busy,so the framework will create another "worker " to process the new message in another thread.

but it seems the akka doesn't do this way,there is only one actor instance.

so I think the "busy actor" will bocking the queue, which will hit the throughout and performance , am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**
If you send messages faster than your Actor can process them, eventually your application will start dropping messages.

**Longer answer:**

As I understand, every Akka Actor has a Queue associated with it, which holds all the messages it receives.

If you send messages to this Actor, faster than the Actor can process them, eventually the queue will overflow, since messages on the queue are kept in ram.

It is not possible to spawn another Actor, on the fly. Since the messages on the queue are processed in order. This ordering will be broken if more than one consumer exists.

I would suggest you take a look at [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.2/scala.html), this is a higher level API built on top of actors, and guards you against this kind of thing by providing backpressure throughout your system. This means that if the actor you're sending messages to is slower than whoever is producing the messages, the consumer will ask the producer to slow down, and will not overflow your Actor's queue.

Comment: Using bounded mailboxes your application will not die, but you'll lose messages in case of overflow.

Comment: @ViktorKlang Updated my answer

Comment: Actually, that depends on whether you use a bounded-blocking or bounded-nonblocking mailbox

Answer (score 1):

Each `Actor` stores their messages in a `Mailbox`.
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/mailboxes.html

The default mailbox is unbounded and non-blocking. If your actor cannot process messages quickly enough, their mailbox balloons in size and consumes increasing amounts of RAM. You can configure Akka to use a bounded, blocking `Mailbox` which will block the sender when over capacity.

If you would like to dynamically manage a pool of actors, look into Routing strategies.
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/scala/routing.html

You can create a `Router` `Actor` that receives messages and passes them to routee actors. The `Router` also manages the routee pool and can dynamically generate routees as needed.

---

Also, if using `Future` and callback asynchronous execution, your actors will not block on http requests.